# Does Maxima have a function for solving systems of linear inequalities, that would also be available on Moodle Stack-exams?

Tags: moodle, maxima, inequality

What's in the title. I've tried the following:

```
/*Constants*/
metalMaxTa : 37;/*rand_with_step(20,40,2);*/
elecMaxTa : 52;/*rand_with_step(40,60,2);*/
rateAa : 24;
rateBa : 44;

/*Conditions set by the problem*/
ineq1 : 1/2 * x1 + x2 <= metalMaxTa;
ineq2 : x1 + 1/2*x2 <= elecMaxTa;
ineq3 : x1 >= 0;
ineq4 : x2 >= 0;

/*Solution?*/
sol : solve_rat_ineq([ineq1,ineq2,ineq3,ineq4],[x1,x2]);
```

but all that returns is this:
[image: System as shown within STACK]

In other words, nothing is really done to the input system, the expression is simply printed. The load-command is not available, so I can't actually load the function if it's not available, which seems to be the problem.

EDIT: `to_poly_solve()` also produces the same output. `solve()` seems to be available, but returns an empty list, as it is apparently meant for systems of equations, not inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

[fourier_elim](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_85.html#IDX2532) can handle it.

```
load('fourier_elim)$

metalMaxTa : 37 $
elecMaxTa : 52  $
rateAa : 24     $
rateBa : 44     $

ineq1 : 1/2 * x1 + x2 <= metalMaxTa$
ineq2 : x1 + 1/2*x2 <= elecMaxTa $
ineq3 : x1 >= 0 $
ineq4 : x2 >= 0 $
sol : fourier_elim([ineq1,ineq2,ineq3,ineq4], [x1, x2]) $
map(disp, sol) $
```

returns

```
                           [x1 = 0, x2 = 0]

                           [x1 = 52, x2 = 0]

                       [x2 = 0, 0 < x1, x1 < 52]

                           [x1 = 0, x2 = 37]

                       [x1 = 0, 0 < x2, x2 < 37]

                                134       44
                          [x1 = ---, x2 = --]
                                 3        3

                          x2 - 104               44
                  [x1 = - --------, 0 < x2, x2 < --]
                             2                   3

                                   44
                  [x1 = 74 - 2 x2, -- < x2, x2 < 37]
                                   3

                               x2
        [0 < x1, x1 < min(52 - --, 74 - 2 x2), 0 < x2, x2 < 37]
                               2
```

It uses only strict inequalities in the output and shows equities as
special cases. If you use strict inequalities in equations the output
looks more natural.

```
                            0 < x1

                               x2
                 x1 < min(52 - --, 74 - 2 x2)
                               2

                            0 < x2

                            x2 < 37
```